# defining sub-domain based on a function in routes.py of Web2Py

Tags: python, blogs, web2py, urlrewriter

I have this page:

```
http://mysite.org/myapp/pages/blog?name=user9
```

and I need to have this:

```
user9.mysite.org
```

What should i write in my routes.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so i think misinterpreted this a little. You need user9.mysite.org to be served from the web2py app. One way, if you have your site hosted at mysite.org, is to pass all requests (regardless of subdomain) to the web2py application (you'll need an A record like *.mysite.org with your DNS provider: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/791/DNS+Explained#/A_Record )

Then, you can use routes

Something like:

```
routes_in = (
  ('http://(?P<user>.*).mysite.org/(?P<any>.*)',
  '/app/pages/blog/\g<any>?name=\g<user>'),
)
```

The <any> will save any args you may need. This should map a request from user9.mysite.org to mysite.org/app/pages/blog/<args>?name=user9

You might have to play with it a little to get it working. The key is to make sure that a request to any subdomain of mysite.org be given directly to the app. Meaning if you go to www.mysite.org, mysite.org, somerandomfakesubdomain.mysite.org, you'll always get to the same place as mysite.org. You'll probably want to put some logic in your blog function to ensure that the subdomain string (e.g. user9) represents a valid user.

Comment: This is a great answer, write it up and submit it to mdpierro as a deployment recipe in the "book"

Comment: @Farsheed -- is your apache vhost setup working properly as well? You need to make sure that all requests regardless of subdomain are routed to rocket or the mod_wsgi/mod_whatever script handler (i.e. to web2py). If that is also correct, then I guess I would wonder what DOES happen with this setup, and what isn't happening that should? Could you post a request URI and the actual routed URI?