# Domain routing with routes package in Python

Tags: python, routes, pylons

I am using the routes package with pylons for my application. Recently, I have another domain which I want to use for some parts of my application.

Can I setup `routing.py` with domain conditions as well? Something like -

```
map.connect('/reviews/', controller = 'reviews', action = 'list', conditions=dict(domain = ['new_domain.com']))
```

I know we can do this for subdomains. I want to know if we can do this with multiple domains as well. So requests coming from different domains to your application can be routed accordingly.

Comment: possibly of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622961/defining-sub-domain-based-on-a-function-in-routes-py-of-web2py - however, I would tend to look at my front-end server doing the work and just delivering it to the app (perhaps introducing some form of header into the request)...

Comment: I am not familiar with that, but just think about if such usage is better handled by a proxy like Nginx or ask yourself why.